# Config resharper navigation (ctrl + T)

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to know whether it is possible to config the Resharper <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> navigation.

Some examples of what I mean:

- Show all classes of type .cs (but not other types, e.g: .config, .js).
- I have `T4MVC` packages and when pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> it shows lots of classes of T4MVC generator which I would like to hide (it just lots of junk files that I wont want to see while searching for types).

Comment: You could go to: Options -> Environment -> Search & Navigation -> Uncheck *Enable Go to Everything*. But this will also disable .config and all kind of files that are not c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I was going through the **`Resharper`** and i noticed there is no direct exposed interface to change the existing shortcut keys for it However maybe conflict resolve will help you. Although it provides you a way to configure addition shortcuts.

## Configuring Keyboard Shortcuts

All ReSharper actions can be invoked with keyboard shortcuts. Most of the actions have default shortcuts, which you can use out of the box. For the rest of the actions, you can assign a preferred shortcut keys if needed.

#### *ReSharper provides two default keyboard shortcuts schemes.*

- **Visual Studio** This scheme aims to minimize conflicts with Visual Studio's own keyboard shortcuts.
- **ReSharper 2.x/IntelliJ IDEA** This scheme shares the majority of shortcuts with those used in IntelliJ IDEA and its derivative web development IDEs. It provides a common keyboard-centric experience among all JetBrains development environments.

Whatever scheme you choose, you can always change individual keyboard shortcuts later.

#### Changing shortcuts and shortcut schemes

When you start Visual Studio for the first time after installing ReSharper, the Keyboard Scheme dialog box opens, where you can choose the default shortcut scheme.

[image]

You can change the selected scheme later using the corresponding selector on the **Environment | Keyboard & Menus** page of ReSharper options.

Regardless of the currently selected scheme, you can always configure individual keyboard shortcuts.

**To configure individual keyboard shortcuts**

1. On the main menu, choose Tools | Options.
2. Expand the Environment node, then click Keyboard.
3. Use the shortcut tables to find the alias
   of the command, to which you are going to assign a new shortcut. If
   some command does not have a default shortcut, you can find its
   alias under the title of the the corresponding help page. For
   example, Convert Method to Indexer.
4. To find a desired command you can also do one of the following:

   - Type the name or a part of the name of the command you are looking for in the Show commands containing field. The list of available commands narrows down and you can easily find the desired one.
   - Look through the list of available commands, scroll down to command names that start with ReSharper.

   Once the list of commands in the Keyboard tab receives
   focus, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to jump to items with initial r.
5. The shortcut key combination of the selected command is displayed in the
   Shortcuts for selected commands drop-down list, if any shortcut
   exists.
6. You can remove the existing key combination(s) and/or add
   the new one(s).

   - Choose the combination in the Shortcuts for selected
     commands drop-down list, then click Remove.
   - The same shortcut key
     combinations can be used in different areas, so you should specify
     the area. Specify the area using the Use new shortcut in drop-down
     list. Then place the caret in the Press shortcut keys text box and
     press the desired key combination. Click Assign.
7. Click OK.

### Resolving Keyboard Shortcut Conflicts

Some keyboard shortcuts are used in the default shortcut schemes, especially in the ReSharper 2.x/IntelliJ IDEA scheme, may be already mapped to other Visual Studio commands. In these cases, ReSharper does not silently replace existing Visual Studio keyboard shortcuts. As soon as you use a conflicting shortcut, i.e. that is used by both the Visual Studio and ReSharper, you are prompted to resolve this conflict using the ReSharper Shortcut Conflict dialog box:

[image]

Select one of three available options:

- **Use ReSharper command:** binds the conflicting shortcut to the ReSharper command.
- **Use Visual Studio commands:** resolves the conflict in favor of the Visual Studio command.
- **Configure ReSharper command:** opens the Keyboard tab in the Visual Studio Options dialog box to help you customize the current keyboard scheme.

Whatever option you choose, you can apply your choice to all other conflicting ReSharper shortcuts by selecting **Apply to all ReSharper shortcuts**.

For more details/Source [please click here...](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Configuring_Keyboard_Shortcuts.html)

***Hoping this will help you :)***